# implementing pedersen commtiment using lib sodium

Tags: implementation, commitments, libsodium

Hi I want to implement pedersen commitment ontop of lib sodium 
Below is what I am trying to do:
comm1: m1G+r1H 
comm2: m2G+r2H 
comm3: (m1+m2)G+(r1+r2)H 
comm4: comm1+comm2

and comm3 should equals comm4 
And here is my code:

```
unsigned char x[crypto_core_ristretto255_HASHBYTES];
randombytes_buf(x, sizeof x);

unsigned char g[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
crypto_core_ristretto255_from_hash(g, x); //compute G

unsigned char h[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
unsigned char x2[crypto_core_ristretto255_HASHBYTES];
randombytes_buf(x2, sizeof x2);
crypto_core_ristretto255_from_hash(h, x2); //compute H

unsigned char r1[crypto_core_ristretto255_SCALARBYTES];
unsigned char hr1[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
unsigned char gm1[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];

crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_random(r1); //generate r1

 if (crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255(hr1, r1, h) != 0) { //compute r1*H
    return -1;
}

unsigned char m1[crypto_core_ristretto255_SCALARBYTES];
randombytes_buf(m1, sizeof m1); //generate m1

// Compute b = a^k
if (crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255(gm1, m1, g) != 0) { //compute m1*G
    return -1;
}
unsigned char comm1[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
crypto_core_ristretto255_add(comm1, gm1, hr1); //compute comm1 = m1*G+r1*H

unsigned char r2[crypto_core_ristretto255_SCALARBYTES];
unsigned char hr2[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
unsigned char gm2[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];

crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_random(r2); //generate r2
if (crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255(hr2, r2, h) != 0) { //compute r2*H
    return -1;
}

unsigned char m2[crypto_core_ristretto255_SCALARBYTES];
randombytes_buf(m2, sizeof m2); //generate m2

if (crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255(gm2, m2, g) != 0) { //compute m2*G
    return -1;
}
unsigned char comm2[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
crypto_core_ristretto255_add(comm2, gm2, hr2); //compute comm2 = m2*G+r2*H

unsigned char r3[crypto_core_ristretto255_SCALARBYTES];
unsigned char hr3[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
unsigned char gm3[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
unsigned char m3[crypto_core_ristretto255_SCALARBYTES];
crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_add(m3, m1, m2); //compute m3 = (m1+m2)
crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_add(r3, r2, r1);//compute r3 = (r1+r2)
if (crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255(hr3, r3, h) != 0) { //compute r3*H
    return -1;
}
if (crypto_scalarmult_ristretto255(gm3, m3, g) != 0) {//compute m3*G
    return -1;
}
unsigned char comm3[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
crypto_core_ristretto255_add(comm3, gm3, hr3); //compute comm3 = m3*G+r3*H
unsigned char comm4[crypto_core_ristretto255_BYTES];
crypto_core_ristretto255_add(comm4, comm1, comm2); //compute comm4 = comm1+comm2
cout<<"sodium cmp: "<<sodium_memcmp(comm3, comm4, sizeof comm3)<<endl;
```

However, the does not equals 0 
Would be truly appreciate having someone provide some insight into any potential mistakes I might be making based on the information I provided above?

Comment: You're using memcmp.  I am unfamiliar with how ristretto represents things internally; however if it uses projective coordinates, there are multiple ways of representing the same curve point, and memcmp (which sodium_memcmp is presumably a wrapper around) would consider two different representations of the same point as different  I would expect ristretto to have a function to compare two points of equality - you might want to try that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i found the issue
I should use crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_random(m) to get the random scalar m

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have found the issue, I should use crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_random(m) to get the random scalar m.